# What is causing the segmentation fault in here?

Tags: c++

It is just a simple code for DFS of an undirected graph which I have tried through recursion.The recursion does terminate here(I'm guessing?).So,what is causing the segmentation fault ? I used the online compilers i.e, jdoodle, and tutorials point.(Okay this is stupid, sorry)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void dfs(vector<int> g[],int n,bool vis[]){
    vis[n]=true;
    cout<<n<<" ";
    for(auto x:g[n]){
        if(!vis[x]) dfs(g,x,vis);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n,e,u,v,i;
        cin>>n>>e;
        bool vis[n]={false};
        vector<int> g[n];
        for(i=0;i<e;i++){
            cin>>u>>v;
            g[u].push_back(v);
            g[v].push_back(u);
        }
        dfs(g,n,vis);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you iterate to e in  for loop  and then access to index u and v that you get from stdin?

Comment: Iterating till e is to get the adjacency list

Comment: You should check the input value for u and v.They should be less than n unless your program may  got signal at g[u].push_back(v); or g[v].push_back(u);.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have out of bounds array access on `g` and `vis` in `dfs`. The size of both arrays is `n` but you access `g[n]` and `vis[n]`.

Maybe you meant to call `dfs(g,0,vis);`???

Comment: OH DEAR ! I should've passed n-1 instead of n in the function call. Such rookie misake. WHY DIDN'T I SEE THAT ? What have I done ! Now I feel stupid

Comment: Thank you for having such a patience to correct this john